# Running R Scripts in PM2 Cluster Mode

Tags: r, pm2

I have an R script that runs fine in Fork mode in PM2. I run it with the command:

```
pm2 -f start --interpreter="Rscript" <path>
```

When I try to run the same in Cluster Mode of PM2 like this

```
pm2 -f start --interpreter="Rscript" <path> -i 2
```

it fails with the following error

```
ReferenceError: setwd is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (<<Path>>.R:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:307:23
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1209:30
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Utility.js:147:13)
```

Should I be making any changes to the R script to enable it to run in cluster mode?

The content of my R script is

```
setwd(<folderpath>)
source("../supportingFile.R")
startWebListener("file.R", 8080)
```

If I remove the setwd command, the same error is being thrown on the source command.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like PM2 tries to pass the number of instances to R script.In general, it is not a good idea to use `setwd` inside scripts.

Comment: So the content of my file is
setwd(<path>) /n
source("../funcs5.R") /n 
startWebListener("name.R", 8080)


How can I change this to not use setwd? And why is it not a good idea to use setwd inside scripts?

Comment: [good read](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/)

Comment: Also, if I remove the setwd command, the same error is getting thrown on the next(source command) line.